How to and a row for the first of the month for a Macro when the date could change
I'm working on a Macro and I was asked if it's possible to have a column display the first of the month from another column. The dates could change if one person leave and someone new comes in. I know I can type the date and use Ctrl+e and it will auto populate For example if D2 is 7 Dec 24 and I type 1 Dec 24 in E2 i can use Ctrl+e and all the cells in Column E will populate the first of the month for each cell going down, caveat if I have a different year I need to type DDMMMYY for that cell first then Ctrl+e. The problem if I try to do this for a Macro I'm typing 1 Dec 24 in E2 but D2 after a few months might now be 25 Oct 25 and now the function doesn't work. Is it possible to do this in a Macro? Below is the end goal for what I'm trying to achieve.


This can be done with a very simple formula, not requiring any VBA macros.
=Date(Year(A1),Month(A1),1)

Copy down. That's it. If the date in A1 changes, the formula will update instantly.

Thank you I'll try this out and as soon as I can and as long as it works I'll mark the question answeres

While the current accepted answer works fine, here is an alternative that only requires you to specify the source-date once:
=EOMONTH(A1, -1)+1

The EOMONTH function returns the end of the nth month before/after the specified date.  -1 means that we ask for the last day of the month before the date in A1, and then we add one to get the 1st of the month after that.
